# vue-tables-2 how to handle the ROW_CLICK event in a module?(vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-tables-2

I've a module named "csv", to handle csv files, and a [vue-tables-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2) with `vuex`:

**Store structure:**

```
-store
 -modules
   -csv.js
 -index.js
```

**index.js:**

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            commons,
            ldap,
            csv <---- I want to execute the mutation in this module
        },
        mutations: {
            ["csvTable/ROW_CLICK"](state, data){
               <---- but now it's running here
            },
        }
    })
```

**csv.js**

```
// initial state
const state = {
    //...
}

// getters
const getters = {
    //...
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    ["csvTable/ROW_CLICK"](state, data){
       < ---I want to execute the mutation here
    }
}

export default {
   //...
}
```

So I want to know how can I execute the ROW_CLICK mutation in the csv module.

I thought I could do it like this:

**index.js:**

```
  ["csvTable/ROW_CLICK"](state, data){
       this.commit(csv/ROW_CLICK, data);
  },
```

But I do not think it's the best way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Learn to use actions.It is recommended to execute your mutations through actions always.

*In **csv.js*** add an action like:

```
   actions: {
     callMutation({commit}, pass_property){ //pass_property is passed to action
       commit('the_mutation_you_want_to_Call',pass_property)
     }
   }
```

*Also the commit object is required to actions to commit mutation.But, if you want, in actions you can use the getters and state as well.See below:*

**Example:**

```
  actions: {
    actionName({commit,getters,state}) {}
  }
```